# Register a JS Function to Apache Jena Fuseki

Tags: javascript, jena, graphdb

How to register JS Function to apache jena fuseki? Is it the same as registering a JS Function to GraphDB.ontotext?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service; therefore, it’s expected that you [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question by including a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We advice to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The starting point is the documentation: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/javascript-functions.html. You need to add  javascript engine such as GraalVM to the Fuseki classpath.

Comment: if i use GraalVM how can i add graalvm to fuseki classpath? thx.

Comment: If you are running the fuseki-server script of any recent version, put them in directory "extra/" where you run Fuskie. There instructions in the script. If you are running a WAR file, you need to rebuild the WAR file (webapp war files by design are sealed).

Comment: I want to ask, if I have ARQ installed on Jena, do I still need GraalVM?

Comment: If you want to add custom functions written in Javascript then Java 11-14 might work with nashorn (IIRC with warnings) in the JDK. Java no longer ships with a javascript engine in the JDK. Deprecated Java 11, removed Java 15. Currently LTS is java 17. Jena Fuseki runs on java11 and above.

Comment: I finally followed your suggestion by installing java 17. Then I made a query to register the java script function that I created. An example query can be seen on this website: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/javascript-functions.html
when I run it, the data is updated. I think that I have succeeded and can implement my js function on the query. but when I implemented the query, it appeared a message: "Unknown scripting language: js". So, what should I do?

Comment: See the link to Jena documentation. There no relationship to GraphDB.

Comment: i know that there is no relation with graph DB. it's just that in this case I use a query from graphDB and then modify the prefix with: PREFIX js: http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/jsFunction# It should work fine by using that prefix.

Comment: That's not how JS functions are supplied to Fuseki. They are not sent by SPARQl Update. See the documentation.